# Reversing the function usage in compose function

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

The [compose](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=compose#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._compose%29%29) function applies last function first, i.e. it applies sent functions in reverse order. For example:

```
((compose sqrt add1) 8)
```

Above will add1 to 8 and then find sqrt of 9.

I want to create a mycompose function which applies first sent function first, and then second, third etc. Hence, in above example, sqrt needs to be applied first and then add1. I could manage following:

```
(define (mycompose L arg)
  (let loop ((L L)
             (res arg))
    (cond
      [(empty? L) res]
      [else (loop (rest L) ((car L) res))])))

(mycompose (list sqrt add1) 8)
```

I am sure there is a better way. Especially, can above be achieved using macros and also permit multiple arguments to be sent to each function turn by turn?

Comment: You could just implement your function as `(define (mycompose . fs) (apply compose (reverse fs))`, which would satisfy all your requirements without needing to be a macro.

Comment: I knew there was a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This “reverse composition” that you describe is often called *thrush*, and [the point-free package provides a `thrush` function](http://docs.racket-lang.org/point-free/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._point-free%2Fmain..rkt%29._thrush%29%29) that does precisely what you want. However, let’s say you wanted to implement it yourself. Well, the easiest way would be to reuse the existing implementation of `compose`, since `thrush` is just `compose` with the arguments reversed:

```
(define (thrush . fs)
  (apply compose (reverse fs))
```

This is, in fact, how the point-free package implements `thrush`. Still, this might be unsatisfying to you, since you don’t know how `compose` is implemented. Well, fortunately, we can implement `thrush` from scratch with a simple fold:

```
(define (thrush . fs)
  (for/fold ([f values])
            ([g (in-list fs)])
    (λ args (call-with-values (thunk (apply f args)) g))))
```

The real trick here is the use of [`call-with-values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-values%29%29), which properly handles functions that return multiple values. Just like Racket’s `compose`, this will accept multiple values and pass them along to functions later in the pipeline as multiple arguments, creating a nice symmetry between function inputs and function outputs.